# Временное хранилище для данных статистики

Tags: php

Есть идея написания своей статистики для сетки сайтов.Смотрел некоторые решения, и почти у всех перед добавлением в базу данных перехода(будем считать это статистикой переходов) складывается все дело у специальные файлы.И потом по *крону* добавляется в базу.Как по мне,это правильно ибо при кучи запросов,сервер упадет.Как этот подход реализован?Какие есть ещё варианты для продуктивной работы системы учета?**(слышал что-то про MEMCACHE хранилище,но что и как - загадка)**

Слышал также про подход записи в виде логов, но как с производительностью...

`IP - XXX || BROWSER - OPERA .....`

Comment: поставьте яндекс или гугл метрику и не парьтесь

Comment: @Etki У меня огромные сети генерированых сайтов и отслеживать по всем ним стату метрикой и так далее не очень круто + там куча не нужного.Вообщем куча причин и надо=)

Comment: я могу вам написать ответ на несколько мониторов, из которого будет следовать один и тот же вывод - проще воспользоваться существующими решениями

Comment: @Etki Напишите, но я точно знаю что не подойдут обычные решения.Мне нужна своя система и я смотрел аналоги.Не подходят =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем вопросе содержится уже один вариант полного ответа на ваш же вопрос.

Ваше приложение добавляет данные о посетителе в текстовый log-файл.

С помощью `cron` консольный скрипт (возможно, написанный на том же php) раз в определенный промежуток времени (минута, час, сутки) разбирает этот файл и складывает информацию в базу данных.

С тем же успехом можно складывать информацию в любое другое хранилище, но, например, `memcached` тут явно не подходит. Это key-value хранилище, и в нем бессмысленно хранить такие списочные данные.

Вместо log-файла можно складывать информацию из приложения в очередь `RabbitMQ` (`ZeroMQ`), и настроить консольный скрипт на разбор очереди.

Альтернативный вариант: отказаться от сбора информации на стороне приложения, и просто настроить формат логов `nginx`. Оттуда можно передавать информацию в `logstash`, который будет их хранить в `elasticsearch`.

С `elasticsearch`, в свою очередь, прекрасно работает `kibana`, как визуальный интерфейс.